# How do I read the version of a deb package without Debian tools?

Tags: package-management, deb

In Archlinux I can open a package, which is just a `.tar.xz`, and then read the `.PKGINFO` file to find out which version of the software I have downloaded.

If, however, I have a `mysoftware-unstable.deb` file, it's not clear where I have to look in order to know the version (or if it's possible to read it at all).

Note that I don't have Ubuntu, nor `apt-get` and the such, I just have a `.deb` file.

Comment: Opening a .deb file on Arch Linux is *possibly* outside the scope of this site, perhaps?

Comment: PS. It may be helpful if you give information about what you're trying to do. Reading information from a .deb file in Arch Linux seems *unusual*, and maybe you're going about something in the wrong way.

Comment: @trr upvoted the second comment, but where else would a question like this go?

Comment: @trr: my question is about the `deb` specification, not Archlinux, so I guess it's either debian-related or ubuntu-related (and there isn't a debian specific stackexchange site :P). However: I'm trying to guess the version of a software that I'm installing through the AUR. The `PKGBUILD` script downloads [this deb file](https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-unstable_current_amd64.deb) which has no version specified in the name. Of course, the version indicated in the `PKGBUILD` is outdated.

Answer (score 6):

You can read the version of a Debian `.deb` package using the `ar` and `tar` commands which should be available, if not installed, on almost all systems.

The following pipeline prints the Debian package `control` file on standard output:

```
ar p mysoftware-unstable.deb control.tar.gz | tar xzOf - ./control
```

The `control` file contains a `Version` field. This example shows the `control` file of the `google-chrome-unstable` package:

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-unstable_current_amd64.deb
$ ar p google-chrome-unstable_current_amd64.deb control.tar.gz | tar xzOf - ./control
Package: google-chrome-unstable
Version: 50.0.2638.0-1
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Chrome Linux Team <chromium-dev@chromium.org>
Installed-Size: 180324
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.14.0)
Depends: gconf-service, libasound2 (>= 1.0.23), libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4), libc6 (>= 2.12), libcairo2 (>= 1.6.0), libcups2 (>= 1.4.0), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.2.14), libexpat1 (>= 1.95.8), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0), libfreetype6 (>= 2.3.9), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libgconf-2-4 (>= 2.31.1), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.26.0), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0), libnspr4 (>= 1.8.0.10), libnss3 (>= 3.17.2), libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.8.0), libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1), libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1), libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1), libxext6, libxfixes3, libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4), libxrandr2 (>= 2:1.2.99.2), libxrender1, libxss1, libxtst6, ca-certificates, fonts-liberation, libappindicator1, libcurl3, lsb-base (>= 4.1), xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2), wget
Provides: www-browser
Section: web
Priority: optional
Description: The web browser from Google
 Google Chrome is a browser that combines a minimal design with sophisticated technology to make the web faster, safer, and easier.
```

Comment: This works, but example usage would be helpful. I.e. `./showcontrol pkg_version_number_amd64.deb`, where `showcontrol` is your script.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use this command

```
dpkg --info yourfile.deb | grep Version
```

Comment: I don't have `dpkg` as stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try info from this page https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/anatomy_of_a_debian_package, using `ar` and tar to extract pkg, I can see below for the google-chrome deb pkg

```
$ cat control
Package: google-chrome-unstable
Version: 48.0.2564.22-1
Architecture: amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in the end:

1. Open the `.deb` file with File roller, or an equivalent archive manager.
   [image: inside of deb file]
2. Then, click on `control.tar.gz`, and go inside the folder named `.`, like this:
   [image: inside of control.tar.gz]
3. Then, click on `control`, and you will finally see the package meta data:

   ```
   Package: google-chrome-unstable
   Version: 48.0.2564.22-1
   Architecture: amd64
   Maintainer: Chrome Linux Team <chromium-dev@chromium.org>
   ... and so on ...
   ```

Comment: mc (Midnight Commander) also works.